Cannot deploy Activiti Cloud on AWS using Amazon EKS
I hope that you are having a great day.
I'm trying to self-host Activiti using a kubernetes cluster as per the instructions here. Everything goes smooth: the resources are created in AWS and listed through the CLI tool, nginx is installed correctly and initially returns a 404 (which makes sense because at that point there are no resources to which nginx can point), etc.
The problem arises when trying to configure a public domain name using Cloudflare (the instructions talk about using Route 53 but we are internally using Cloudflare). I set a CNAME record with a wildcard (`*.activiti.my-enterprise.com) and I associate it with the public IP of my load balancer, as per these instructions.
Even after doing everything asked in the docs, I still get errors related either the SSL handshake not being able to complete, or HTTP error codes shown by nginx (400 and 502 specifically).
I've searched in forums and I haven't found any information regarding this. What do you all think could be going wrong?
